# Ruby on Rails - RSpec test for direct route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a direct route like so:

```
direct :homepage do
  "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
end
```

And I am trying to test this but I am not sure how. This is what I have:

```
describe 'redirect' do
  it 'directs to homepage', type: :request do
    get :homepage
    expect(response).to redirect_to('http://www.rubyonrails.org')
  end  
end
```

But this fails:

```
1) redirect directs to homepage
     Failure/Error: get :homepage

     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): "http://www.example.com:80homepage"
```

I have the url_helpers included in my Rspec config.

How do I test a direct route?

See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#direct-routes

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I wrote this example, it became clear.

```
describe 'redirect' do
  it 'directs to homepage' do
    expect(homepage_url).to eq('http://www.rubyonrails.org')
  end
end
```

I was writing my test in request specs. This works.